# Como selecionar valor Option com retorno de dados Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```
<select id="priorities-info" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" disabled="" tabindex="-98">
    <option value="1" data-tokens="Alta">Alta</option>
    <option value="2" data-tokens="Média">Média</option>
    <option value="3" data-tokens="Baixa">Baixa</option>
</select>
```

Estou tentando comparar o data-tokens desta forma:

```
$('#priorities-info').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('selected', this.dataset.tokens == responseData.Type);
});
```

Mas não estou conseguindo, alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Qual o valor de `responseData.Type`?

Comment: @Marconi `Type: Média`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seletor acredito que você deva incluir os options e verificar se o valor do atributo `data-tokens` é igual ao retornado pelo ajax:

```js
$('#priorities-info option').each(function() {
  if ( $(this).attr('data-tokens') == 'Média')
    $(this).prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="priorities-info" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" tabindex="-98">
    <option value="1" data-tokens="Alta">Alta</option>
    <option value="2" data-tokens="Média">Média</option>
    <option value="3" data-tokens="Baixa">Baixa</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Obrigado Lucas, só uma observação se alguém estiver utilizando o **Bootstrap Select**
igual a mim, aconselho a colocar `$('#priorities-info').selectpicker('refresh');` após o `if`

Comment: Maravilha @WagnerViana!